# IOS Simulator session timed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I am trying to run UIAutomation from terminal and getting "simulator session timed out". I have no idea whats going on.

I have tried everything on earth i could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Its due to permission of the folder where the app was getting built.

So, the ios simulator is running in user context and i was building the app using sudo (in root permissions). So, the ios simulator did not have access to the build because of the permissions.

So, now i set the entire folder to everyone or loggedin user permissions using finder and its working great.

Comment: The reason i had to do is that on the macosx server, the scripts were at ... root level and not Users level.

So when i ran the script to build it wont allow me to build and it will eventually fail.

sudo was definitely a bad idea, cause later on i changed permissions to the user from system and i didn't have to add sudo anymore.

so, it was basically because of sudo the simulator didnt have access   to the .app file needed by the ios simulator to run.