# Facebook Simulator Build

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that there are loads of answers to that kind of question I'm asking, but non of them worked for me.
The problem is that I'm trying to send Simulator Build to Facebook. For that I used the following steps:

On the terminal - I'm running the following commands:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 -workspace  MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp  (I'm getting "Build Secceded")
sudo iOS-sim launch Path_to_MyApp.app
```

When I run second command, this is what I get:

```
"Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7ffc0263ec70 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}"
```

What can I do to make iOS-sim work?

Comment: Sometimes this might help you to resolve the issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521761/1208276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is another way and it worked for me..

1. reset your app from the simulator.
2. run this command on terminal: xcrun simctl install booted "Path_to_YourApp.app"

Now you'll see the app on your simulator again. just open it and see if it works.
hope it will help someone.